# Regular expression Range with decimal 0.10 - 99.99

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that should validate decimal point as well as range. Totally 4 number should be present including dot and the value must be greater than 0.0. That means the valid range is from 0.01〜99.99

this my regex :::  `-?[0-9]*([1-9][0-9]*(.[0-9]*)?|.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)`

but this accept above 99.99

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not really how this site works - it's not a code writing service, but members are very happy to help if you show a little effort at solving the problem yourself. The fact that your title contradicts the text of your request shows a lack of effort as well.

Comment: Any special reason it has to be a regex? There are much easier ways to validate numbers. What is the context?

Comment: as per our development we should validate with regex

Comment: -?[0-9]*([1-9][0-9]*(.[0-9]*)?|.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)  this regex working fine but should not accept more than 99.99

Comment: @LingrajGowda "as per our development we should validate with regex" is not a good reason. What is the context? Is this client-side or server-side? Which language/environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you get some idea from this:

```
Pattern  : ^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}$|^\d{1,2}$

Match 1
Full match  0-4 0.01
Match 2
Full match  5-10    99.99
Match 3
Full match  11-16   01.01
```

https://regex101.com/r/p03CtT/4

Comment: This matches `01q77` or `123` and many other undesirable inputs.

Comment: its not working as i want  0.10 - 99.99  range required

Comment: @Abimanyu it's working fine but when I convert to  ^[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}$|^[0-9]{1,2}$    is not working

Comment: @LingrajGowda, Use this ^[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}$|^[0-9^\w]{1,2}$

Comment: @Abimanyu its working 0 should not allowed. how to do that one

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

^[0-9]{1,2}.[1-9][0-9]{0,1}$|^[1-9][0-9]{0,1}.[0-9]{1,2}$

i tried in my editor and it worked..